# Laptop overheating, Unity / OpenGL / nvidia drivers conflict

Tags: unity, nvidia, overheating, opengl

My problem is that my laptop, Dell Inspiron N5110, running ubuntu 12.04, is overheating, and occasionally shuts down voluntarily.  The fan is working non-stop.

*I know much has been reported/asked/answered about problems similar to mine, but I've been reading and experimenting with solutions suggested for days now, and none of them helped.*

**My current diagnostic is that:**

1. when not using `nvidia-current`, the laptop overheats and shuts down very often.
2. when using `nvidia-current`, I *think* the overheating problem gets better, but unity falls back to unity-2d (`Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". Error: GLX is not available on the system`), which I dislike.

All the answers I found about the opengl/unity problem involve getting rid of the nvidia drivers.

**Other notes:**

1. The fan is working non-stop.  AFAICT, this isn't a fan-hardware problem.
2. As suggested in many places, I'm using `pcie_aspm=force` in my `/etc/default/grub`. It doesn't seem to make a difference.
3. The only way I found to prevent my laptop from shutting down too often, is by using `Jupiter`, and setting its mode to `Performance -> Power Saving`.  Obviously, this sucks.  It stills shuts down occasionally, tough.
4. I'm currently using ubuntu 12.04 and kernel 3.2.0-40-generic.  I had the same problems with ubuntu 11.10 / kernel 3.0.

**Additional command output**

```
% lspci| grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: your laptop doesn't have optimus? Please include result of `lspci| grep VGA`

Comment: @Web-E, added output of `lspci| grep VGA`

Comment: See here - [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/a/156120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bumblebee Project

Bumblebee aims to provide support for NVIDIA Optimus laptops for GNU/Linux distributions. Using Bumblebee, you can use your NVIDIA card for rendering graphics which will be displayed using the Intel card.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update
```

Install Bumblebee using the default proprietary nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

Add the following line in /etc/modules

```
 sudo gedit /etc/modules
 bbswitch load_state=0
```

**save and exit**

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**Reboot**   **Done**

[How TO USE OPTIMUS CARD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

For More Power Saving and Make Laptop Coller

[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681)

---

**I have Same Model Dell Inspiron N5110 i7 , Intel HD 3000 and Nvidia GeForce GT 525M**

Comment: dell inspiron specs http://www.dell.com/ae/p/inspiron-15r-n5110/pd

Comment: thanks. I'll try it out shortly. Can you confirm there are no opengl/unity problems?

Comment: the 1st thing after installation i do is to install bumblebee ..

Comment: @shx2 i recommend you is to install Ubuntu 13.04 ..clean installation ... y ? cauzz all key board and touch pad driver are included in it...all FUN keys are working ....

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287253/reduced-performance-in-bumblebee-after-3-0-to-3-2-update/288517#288517

Comment: @Qasim I didn't get the idea of `bbswitch load_state=0`, anyway bumblebee gonna disable the card at boot. isn't it?

Comment: yes........ just copy paste this command > sudo echo bbswitch load_state=0 >> /etc/modules && sudo update-initramfs -u